# Why session value in php keep incrementing every time the page refreshed

Tags: php, web, reference, e-commerce

I am new to PHP and I am using session variables to create shopping cart, as I need to increment the number of items in the cart, I use session variables. However, this variable keep increment every time the page refreshed/reload, which increment the number of items.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['items'])){

    $_SESSION['items'] = 0;
}

function increament_items(){
    $_SESSION['items']++;
}
?>
```

and in HTML I have this

```
<a id="laptop" href="index.php" onclick="<?php increament_items() ?>",title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]">
```

I have tried to use form using post/get and still the same. 
any help?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php, as it is not a client language, will not work "onclick", but every time the code

```
<a id="laptop" href="index.php" onclick="<?php increament_items() ?>",title="header=[Add to cart] body=[&nbsp;] fade=[on]">
```

Is loaded.

So, you could use something like this to solve your problem.

1) Add at the end of your php code this:

```
if($_GET['add']==1){
increament_items();
}
```

2a) Then, replace your html code with this one

```
<a id="laptop" href="nameofyourphppage.php?add=1">Add</a>
```

2b) Or, if you prefer, after having included jquery library (*) into html page, use the following one:

```
<script>
function openLink(url)
{$("#add").html('Loading...');
$("#add").load(url, function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#add").html('An error occurred');
   }
});
}
</script>
    <a id="laptop" href="javascript:openLink('nameofyourphppage.php?add=1')">Add</a>
<div id="add"></div>
```

The second solution will run the php code without the user leaving the html page.

(*)To include the jquery library, put into the head section of your html page this code:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it, I used your first approach ant it works now, my final function is
if($_GET['add']==1){
increament_items();
header("location: index.php");
}